# Yii2. Выгрузка на пдф файл не всю базу только одну строку

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, mysqli

Здраствуйте, я новичок, использую yii2. Я хотел вы сделать ссылку на выгрузку или MуSql запрос из БД на пдф, не всю базу а только одну строку и связанных данные с других таблиц с этой строкой.
Как это делается? Где смотреть? Что использовать?

Comment: *не всю базу а только одну строку* `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Либо еще так ->limit(1)